# Multithreading not working (not faster than single threading)

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, future

I'm trying to test multithreading with a simple summation task, in which I want to compare single thread vs multi thread.

Single thread:

```
long long summation(int start, int end)
{
    long long total = 0; 
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        total += i;
    }
    return total;
}
```

and Multi thread:

```
long long threadedSummation(int numThreads, int start, int end)
{
    long long total = 0;
    int summationRange = (start + end) / numThreads; //The range of numbers for every thread to calculate
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
    {
        int start = summationRange * i;
        int end = summationRange * i + summationRange;
        total += async(launch::async, summation, start, end).get(); //The async function launches
    }
    return total; //returns value
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't have better runtime. with a test of start = 0, end = 10000000000 I get:

> SINGLE THREADED: 739026695568526336,  DURATION: 1.21866

> MULTI THREADED: 739026695568526336, DURATION: 1.28625

So it's not better, and I think there must be something wrong with the code, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you read about what [`get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get) does

Comment: You are not running it in parallel. In `get` it is waiting for the calculation to complete.

Comment: This code isn't using multithreading correctly and simply adds complexity to the program, making it perform worse than the singlethreaded equivalent. Waiting on an asynchronous action to complete is basically a synchronous action.

Comment: I did read what `get` does, but any help understanding my mistake better would work. maybe it's that `get` is halting the code?

Comment: And how can I make it asyncronous, without using get?

Comment: @cheveuxdelin create all the futures first, and then start waiting on them.

Comment: I suppose you start them all, storing the objects returned by async somewhere, then wait for each of them to finish and sum the get() results.

Comment: Apart from all the trouble around the implementation itself you need be aware that multi-threading does not come for free. For each thread a stack must be reserved, further infrastructure initialised and the thread must be added to the thread scheduling. All these costs must first be amortised before you can profit from multi-threading, so the work to be done must be large enough. On a single processor system, you cannot profit at all, as thread execution needs to be serialised anyway. But the context switches needed for are costly, too.

Comment: By the way, I'd be curious to see your program -- for example, passing 1E10 as an int parameter will not work. Overflowing int is UB, even if it hasn't hurt anybody since 1973 or so. Even long long will only get you up to ~4E9 because the sum goes with the square... I understand the result is irrelevant here and the computing time is not affected by the overflow but still.

Comment: The program is just that, those 2 functions, and the call of both functions on main with 1E10 :=)

Comment: Well, just switch to *unsigned* integer types and the UB is eliminated. Overflow of unsigned types has well defined behaviour (modulo 2^size in bits).

Answer (score 6):

By immediately calling `.get()` you're running only a single thread at any time. Collect the `std::future` in a `std::vector` and then after all of them are created you can use `.get()` once they're running in parallel:

```cpp
long long threadedSummation(int numThreads, int start, int end)
{
    long long total = 0;
    int summationRange = (start + end) / numThreads;
    std::vector<std::future<long long>> futures{};

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
    {
        int start = summationRange * i;
        int end = summationRange * i + summationRange;
        futures.emplace_back(async(launch::async, summation, start, end));
    }

    for (auto& future : futures)
    {
        total += future.get();
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: @cheveuxdelin out of curiosity, what was the benchmarked time with this change?

Comment: with a ryzen 9 4900 using its 16 threads, I got:
SINGLE THREADED: 994142226714070528,  DURATION: 1.23639
MULTI THREADED: 994142226714070528, DURATION: 0.197403
(same testcase of 10000000000). average 600%

Comment: So 6 cores needed roughly 1/6 of the time... sounds plausible ;-). Oh, wait: 8 cores need 1/6... even more plausible! (My 6 core needs about 1/5).

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the futures and sum them at the end.

```
long long threadedSummation(int numThreads, int start, int end)
{
    long long total = 0;
    int summationRange = (start + end) / numThreads; //The range of numbers for every thread to calculate

  std::vector <std::future<long long>> results;
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
    {
        int start = summationRange * i;
        int end = summationRange * i + summationRange;
        results.emplace_back(async(launch::async, summation, start, end)) ; //The async function launches
    }

  // get the results from the futures then sum them
  //... 

    return total; //returns value
}
```

Comment: @NathanOliver sorry not at the compute yet. Fixing it.